# Браузер на Android на полный экран

Tags: android, браузер, chromium

Есть девайс на Android 4.2, в котором установлен Chromium (но можно установить и что-то другое). Задача состоит в том, чтобы запустить его сразу в полноэкранном режиме. В chrome на десктопе, например, это делается через ключ --kiosk. Т.е. пользователь не должен видеть строки с адресом и т.п.

Comment: а не проще WebView сделать в приложении на весь экран?

Comment: Как уже было отмечено нужно использовать WebView. Розместить его по всей широте и высоте и вы получите ожидаемый результат.

Comment: Спасибо, ваши советы являются решением, но требуют установки пакета для разработки. Необходимый функционал получилось найти в браузере Dolphin.